# Should the `xxd` utility be listed as a dependency in my application?

Tags: linux, xxd

I'm distributing a desktop application and I'm unsure if `xxd` should be listed as a (build) dependency.

My first though was not, since it's documented in the [Linux manpages](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/xxd.html) and therefore should be available on all Linux machines, shoudln't it? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

However I recently received some issues saying that the `xxd` was missing in their systems (Arch on Steam Deck and Debian).

Doing some research found that in some distros the `xxd` binary is **only** distributed alongside vim as a dependency (See [this](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/which-package-provides-xxd-could-not-figure-it-out/15866) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5yznre/xxd_is_missing_in_neovim_package_in_arch_linux/)), which confuses me even more, so I now depend on vim to be installed?

Should I list `xxd` as a dependency or leave it up to the user to have the binary installed?

Comment: Man pages on linux.org will cover most of the utilities that *can* be installed on a system. The choice of what packages are actually installed is up to the administrator. Do you have [sl](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/sl.html) installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since it's documented in the Linux manpages and therefore should be available on all Linux machines, shoudln't it? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

You're wrong. Having a man page has nothing to do with being available everywhere (there's literally no single specific program that's available on *every* Linux system. Some embedded systems don't even *have* a user land, and others have e.g. the Android user land.)

> Doing some research found that in some distros the xxd binary is only distributed alongside vim as a dependency (See this and this), which confuses me even more, so I now depend on vim to be installed?

`xxd` is simply part of the vim source code – that's just how it is. `ls` and `rm`, for example part of the `coreutils` source code. Don't sweat it. The package that contains an executable not necessarily is called like the executable.

However, on "modern" debian (at least going back to debian buster, so, three debian releases ago), `xxd` [is its own package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xxd). That does not depend on vim. So, I'm not sure whether you should trust your information sources!

> Should the `xxd` utility be listed as a dependency in my application?

We can't answer your question, because you haven't told us what your application (or its users) needs `xxd` for. If it's necessary to *build* your application, then it's a *build dependency*. If it's necessary to *run* your application, it's usually just called a *dependency*. It might be either, none or both.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! About wat you said: "_there's literally no single specific program that's available on every Linux system_" this is pretty daunting for apps distributors. If my application is distributed for Linux-based desktop users I would expect their systems to have basic build utilities and not have to list every single command that I've used in the installation process. Is there any rule of thumb that I can follow to decide if a binary is widely available (like `rm`, `wc`, `tee`) so is not necessary to list it as a dependency?

Comment: For Linux-based **desktop** users, things are a fair bit more uniform, so yeah, you can expect `rm` to be there. I would assume `wc` to be there as well, and `tee`. But if you're building Linux-distro-specific packages, you will have to refer to the guides of the respective distro, anyways. Does your application need `wc` at runtime?

Comment: `xxd` is something that is very rarely used, and it's definitely not part of any "baseline" Linux installation I'd be aware of. Is it something your program needs at **runtime** or to **build** the program?

Comment: Just for building. I tend to not depend on external binaries at runtime. I used `xxd` [here](https://github.com/paoloose/urn/blob/main/Makefile#L25) to create a hex dump of a css file as a C header style that will be compiled with the rest of the application code (autogenerates `unsigned char urn_gtk_css[] = { 0x2e, 0x77, 0x69, ... }`).

Comment: so, then, I honestly don't understand the question – it clearly *is* a build-time dependency to you, so you *should* declare it as such!

Comment: Fair enough, so I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: @perrocallcenter you're welcome. However, I kind of have to wonder why you're converting the ASCII text there to its character representation. Literally including it as `unsigned char urn_gtk_css = ".window { …";` would have the same effect - and you wouldn't need `xxd` for that, a simple `printf 'unsigned char urn_gtk_css = "' > urn-gtk.h; awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' urn-gtk.css >> urn-gtk.h; printf '";\n'` would do

Comment: If you're building on Debian (and derivatives like Ubuntu or Mint), you don't have to list packages tagged as "Essential: yes", they're guaranteed to be installed. That includes packages like `apt`, `basefiles`, `bash`, `coreutils`, `dpkg`, `findutils`, `grep`, `libc-bin`, `sed`, `util-linux`, and more . You can see a list of these Essential packages with `apt list ~E`.  All other packages are optional and **must** be listed as a Depends or Build-Depends if they are required to run or build your package.  See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html#priority

Comment: There are also packages tagged as "Priority: required", which are a superset of "Essential: yes" packages.  They are automatically installed too - the difference is that apt & dpkg will refuse to remove *essential* packages (unless you use the `--force-remove-essential` option to deliberately break your system) but will remove *required* packages without complaint (also removing any other packages that depend on them either directly or indirectly...and almost certainly break your system).